# Java GUI: Cannot find Symbol buildPanel()

Tags: java, swing

I have started experimenting with Swing and AWT recently and am following the book Starting out with Java by Tony Gaddis. I am trying to generate a window where a value in Kilometres is converted into miles. I am using the NetBeans IDE. As IDEs go, they throw up probable errors as and when you type the code. So I encountered this error and have not proceeded beyond it.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class KilometerConvertor extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel messagelabel;
    private JTextField kilotextfield;
    private JButton calcbutton;

    public KilometerConvertor(int L,int H)
    {
        setTitle("Kilometre to Miles Converter");
        setSize(L,H);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        buildPanel();
        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

There is this bulb with a red symbol next to the line with buildPanel();. I went through a lot of existing threads on the site where the most common mistakes are spelling errors. So I have checked my code for such errors too.

Comment: what is `buildPanel();`  ?

Comment: it builds a panel and adds it to the frame

Comment: No it does not, because it's obviously missing from the code you posted.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's there, right below the line with: setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Comment: Yes, thank you. I just realised it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You copied to much without understanding it yet. The methods `setTitle(String)`, `setSize(int, int)`, `setDefaultCloseOperation(int)`, `add(Component)`, `setVisible(Boolean)` are all defined in the `JFrame` class you're extending.

The `buildPanel()` method is probably just a placeholder in the book you're reading. You have to add this method to your class, e.g.

```
private void buildPanel() {
    this.panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3));
    this.messageLabel = new JLabel("Input: ");
    this.kilotextfield = new JTextField();
    this.calcbutton = new JButton("Calculate");

    this.panel.add(this.messageLabel);
    this.panel.add(this.kilotextfield);
    this.panel.add(this.calcButton);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I got it! Thank you. I got confused with the fact that I was using a method before declaring it!